# How to save multiple high scores in C

Tags: c

This is for the hangman game. How can I save a few names and scores?

```
FILE *fscore;
fscore=fopen("scores.txt","r+");
fprintf(fscore," new score %s = %d\n",player,n);
fclose(fscore);
```

For example like this:

```
nancy = 13

michal = 50

nina = 10
```

Comment: `fprintf` them as you just did?

Comment: For saving during runtime, e.g. for further processing, you might want to use what is called an array, filled in what is called a loop. If you cannot predict the number/size, you end up with dynamic memory.

Comment: this code only give one name and one score

Comment: how to use array for this? sorry i'm new in c

Comment: In that case find a tutorial, start from helloworld and work upwards. Arrays and loops will be explained in the first 3 hours of any tutorial. Use your favorite search engine on "C programming tutorial".

Comment: You can do it however you want, think about it, in the end you are writing whatever string you want to the file. So for starters just try to concatenate it the way you want it to be.

Comment: Just think and search about how to create that exact thing you wrote right there: "nancy=13 \n michael=50 \n nina=10 \n".